# How popular OSes handle localhost connections?

Tags: performance, localhost

Is there any noticeable overhead when sending data? Or systems are smart enough to optimize it and it's practically as fast as coping data within RAM?

Answer (score 1):

In every OS I've used, IP traffic to `localhost` never touches [Layer 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_1) (the physical media, e.g., Ethernet).  The packets are turned around in memory and head back up the stack.